# Attunity component Source and Destination for Oracle in Visual Studio 2019 SSIS

Tags: ssis, toolbox, attunity

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 community Edition. SqlServer Data tools. And the Attunity component for SSIS.

I downloaded and installed the component from the Microsoft Attunity/Oracle download.  The Oracle Source and Oracle Destination does not show up in the SSIS designer toolbox.  Nor does it show up in the standard toolbox using Choose Item. The dialog doesn't show Oracle Source or Oracle Destination.

Can't call Attunity.  They were bought by Qlik.

Help?  :<

Comment: You should be able to download alternate versions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/attunity-connectors

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have tried all of those suggestions.  Searched all over the Google universe.  StackOverflow was my last hope.  I have SQL 2017 installed, and VS 2019.  Got the latest Attunity adapter from Microsoft.  Same problem.  The component does not show up.

Comment: Is your project targeting SQL Server 2017? With the project open, you can check by going to `Project -> Properties` from the menu bar, and then going to the `General` heading under `Configuration Properties`.